# View based on two tables with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hope you can help me with the query.

I have two tables and I want to generate the view from it but I want that to happen based on some condition.

[image]

So basically I wish to have a view which uses tbl02 to overwrite level of existing ldap in tbl01.

Something like if user02 exists in TBL02 use level from it instead of level from tbl01.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a left outer join and use ISNULL to display lvl from TBL02 unless it doesn't exist then use lvl from TBL01 instead.

```
SELECT TBL01.ldap, ISNULL(TBL02.lvl, TBL01.lvl), TBL01.Firstname, TBL01.LastName
FROM TBL01
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL02 ON TBL01.ldap = TBL02.ldap
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a join and take the level from the second table, I believe it will do the trick.

```
SELECT a.ldap, b.lvl, a.Firstname, a.Lastname FROM TBL01 a JOIN TBL02 b ON a.ldap = b.ldap
```